# async/await in function synchronous - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i have this code :

```
const delay = () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));

async function displayScore(score) {
  await delay();
  console.log(score);
}

async function processScores(scores) {
  forEach(scores, async (score) => {
    await displayScore(score);
  });
}

processScores([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Why am I getting the message that forEach is not defined?

Comment: Because `forEach` is not a function but a method of an array: `scores.forEach()`.

Comment: (as well as some other things, like NodeList)

Comment: @EmielZuurbier though even that [doesn't work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37576685/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error `forEach is not defined` because there is no such function called `forEach()`. There is, though, a method `Array.prototype.forEach()`:

```js
scores.forEach(async score => {
...
});
```